# Remove htmlentities(.*) from code with PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre

I am migrating an old code base to a new database which is in UTF-8. I am also using Eloquent so I do not have to worry about SQL injection anymore.

After converting all the database content in UTF-8 and removing HTML entities, I need to remove every call to htmlentities. So I wrote this:

```
htmlentities\s*\(
(?<e>[^()]*(?:\((?&e)\)[^()]*?)*)
(?:,\s*ENT_\w+)?
(?:\s*\,'UTF-8')?
\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/2RpH3L/2

My regular expression is too greedy and it does not work as expected. For example:

```
htmlentities(foobar(), ENT_QUOTE, 'UTF-8');
             ^--------------------------^ Match this
             ^------^ Instead of this
```

I could do the job in two steps with Perl:

```
perl -pi -e '\
    s/htmlentities\s*\((?<e>[^()]*(?:\((?&e)\)[^()]*?)*)\)/\
       s@^(.*?)(?:,\s*(?:ENT_\w+|'UTF-8')\s*)*$@$1@\
    /gme
```

Is there a way to do it in plain PCRE?

Comment: In your demo the entire call is matched. What's wrong?

Comment: @revo, This is precisely my question. I don't understand why the entire call is matched.

Comment: I read this from your question `I need to remove every call to htmlentities` and assume that you need to match the entire call to remove it. So how do you want to perform a removal?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to match the first parameter so you can replace htmlentities with the first param, ie the value?